# C++ struct conversion to C# struct with unions

Tags: c#, c++, struct, mfc

I have source code in MFC(C++) and have some complex structs with unions. And I having difficulties to convert them to C# code.
There is `in6_addr` struct.

```
    typedef struct in6_addr {
    union {
        UCHAR       Byte[16];
        USHORT      Word[8];
    } u;
} IN6_ADDR, *PIN6_ADDR, FAR *LPIN6_ADDR;
```

and `in_addr` struct

```
typedef struct in_addr {
        union {
                struct { UCHAR s_b1,s_b2,s_b3,s_b4; } S_un_b;
                struct { USHORT s_w1,s_w2; } S_un_w;
                ULONG S_addr;
        } S_un;
#define s_addr  S_un.S_addr /* can be used for most tcp & ip code */
#define s_host  S_un.S_un_b.s_b2    // host on imp
#define s_net   S_un.S_un_b.s_b1    // network
#define s_imp   S_un.S_un_w.s_w2    // imp
#define s_impno S_un.S_un_b.s_b4    // imp #
#define s_lh    S_un.S_un_b.s_b3    // logical host
} IN_ADDR, *PIN_ADDR, FAR *LPIN_ADDR;
```

which are defined by Microsoft. Using these struct there is another struct `_TUNNELINFO`

```
typedef struct _TUNNELINFO
{
    union {
        IN6_ADDR    In6Addr;
        IN_ADDR       In4Addr;
    } U_Addr;

#define TIAddr4     U_Addr.In4Addr
#define TIAddr6     U_Addr.In6Addr

    IN_ADDR        LocalAddr;
    IN_ADDR        RemoteAddr;

    USHORT        LocalPort;
    USHORT        RemotePort;
    UCHAR        TunnelType;

    UCHAR        VrType;
    USHORT       vrID;
    UCHAR        PrefixLength;

    ULONG        Flag;
    ULONG        GoodTransmits;
    ULONG        GoodReceives;
} TUNNELINFO, *PTUNNELINFO;
```

I used pinvoke.net to find `in6_addr` and `in_addr` C# definitions. There is my `_TUNNELINFO` C# struct. But it seems wrong.

```
public struct _TUNNELINFO
        {    
           [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
           public struct U_Addr
            {
                [FieldOffset(0)]
                public in6_addr In6Addr;
                [FieldOffset(0)]
                public in_addr In4Addr;
            }
            public U_Addr u_Addr;

            public in_addr LocalAddr;
            public in_addr RemoteAddr;

            public ushort LocalPort;
            public ushort RemotePort;
            public byte TunnelType;

            public byte VrType;
            public ushort vrID;
            public byte PrefixLength;

            public uint Flag;
            public uint GoodTransmits;
            public uint GoodReceives;
        };
```

Is there anyone who can help to resolve that?
Thank you!

Comment: Why does it seem wrong?

Comment: Please add the error you faced ?